# How does an adventurer Disengage from melee?

Tags: runequest-glorantha

In a throwaway line in the new [RuneQuest Glorantha’s quickstart rules](https://www.chaosium.com/runequest-roleplaying-in-glorantha-quickstart/), under Movement (p. 8), it’s noted that movement isn’t possible until disengaged from melee:

> An adventurer engaged in melee cannot move until disengaged.

However, that section ends abruptly there, and the rules move on to a discussion of Runes.

How does a combatant disengage from melee?

Answer (score 6):

That’s not addressed in the Time & Movement section. You have to keep reading (past Runes, Passions, and Skills rules sections) to get the general rules for combat starting on page 12.

The layout is a bit misleading, in the garden-path sense, because the preceding rules on making weapon skill rolls, detailed workings of the Strike Ranks initiative/action system, and combat movement would seem to be nearly complete enough for “quickstart” combat rules, and because previously when the Quickstart has referenced later rules it had included forward references. However, there’s more to the combat system — the rules just get back to it several pages later. A better layout — or a more patient reader — would clear it up.

The rules for disengaging are on page 14. In short, disengaging is possibly by making a controlled retreat (defending without attacking, no movement until next turn), turning around and running away (faster — immediate movement — but provokes a free attack), or just hitting the opponent hard enough to push *them* away from melee engagement range (Knockback rules). These options aren’t detailed there except descriptively, and their consequences are caused by the previous Movement rules and the Knockback rules (on the next page).

Comment: (Seriously I feel dumb now for having the initial question, but it took me several consternated minutes of reading interruption before I figured out what the answer was. I take comfort that probably someone else will too, and maybe this will help them.)